# How can I efficiently and elegantly determine, based on the name of a nested element, which list it belongs to?

Tags: r, list

I have a list which have iterable elements:

```
my_list <- list(
  A = list(apple = 1:3, orange = "abc"),
  B = tibble(banana = "qwerty", strawberry = 1:5),
  C = data.frame(blueberry = "xyz", mango = "something")
)
```

I would like to where is, say, "blueberry". Since, it is a name of a column that belongs to a data.frame that is under name C. So by the input "blueberry", I should get "C".

I wrote the following function, but I am wondering whether there is a more elegant (efficient) solution for this?

```
find_list <- function(name, my_list) {
  idx <- which(sapply(my_list, function(x) name %in% names(x)))
  if (length(idx) > 0) {
    return(names(my_list)[idx])
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

# Test
print(find_list("strawberry", my_list))  # Prints "B"
print(find_list("mango", my_list))       # Prints "C"
print(find_list("apple", my_list))       # Prints "A"
print(find_list("nonexistent", my_list))  # Prints NULL if the name is not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this sort of approach and turn it into a function...

```
gsub("\\..+", "", grep("blueberry", names(unlist(my_list)), value = TRUE))

[1] "C"
```

`unlist` produces nested names separated by dots, so the first element is the top level list you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `Filter`:

```
find_list <- function(nm, lst) {
  res <- names(Filter(\(x) nm %in% names(x), lst))
  if (length(res) > 0) return (res) else (NULL)
}
```